# Change Postgresql version that Postgres.app uses

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew, postgresapp

When I use Postgres.app, it uses version `9.6`.

I have version `10.5` installed as well (via Homebrew) on my computer and want to use that instead.

When clicking on the `+` sign in the sidebar to "Create new server" I only get a dropdown with versions `9.5`, `9.6` and `10`.

[image]

How do I instruct Postgress.app to use 10.5?

Answer (score 1):

The version you installed with brew is in a different $PATH. It is an independent installation from the one you installed with Postgres.app

Answer (score 1):

You would have to install the corresponding version of the app which supports your required version from this link, in your case last option might work. https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html

[image: Screenshot of docs page]